# reading a qr code from image C# MVC4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, emgucv

I have a Jquery Webcam plugin which saves an Image from the Webcam, this works perfectly fine and i can see it in my C drive.

Now ive add the Emgu CV library. when i press the "capture QR Code" to decode a QR code from the image saved, it wont display the QR's Url to the Viewbag.Result, any ideas what i am doing wrong? below is my code involving the webcam and Emgu CV

Webcam.cshtml

```
  @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Webcam";
}
@section scripts
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.webcam.js")">
    </script>
    <script>
        $("#Camera").webcam({
             width: 400,
             height: 320,
             mode: "save",
             swffile: "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jscam.swf")",
             onTick: function () { },
             onSave: function () { },
             onCapture: function () {
                 webcam.save("@Url.Content("~/QR/Capture")/");
             },
             debug: function () { },
             onLoad: function () { }
         });
     </script> 
}

<section id ="loginForm">
    <input type="button" value="Capture QR Code" onclick="webcam.capture();" />

<div id="Camera"></div>
<p>1. Take Picture of QR Code in front of the webcam</p>


<p>@ViewBag.Result </p>

</section>
```

QR Controller

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO;
using Emgu.CV;
using ZXing;
using System.Drawing;



namespace JobTracker.Controllers
{
public class QRController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /QR/

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Webcam()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public void Capture()
    {
        var stream = Request.InputStream;
        string dump;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            dump = reader.ReadToEnd();

        var path = Server.MapPath("~/QR.jpg");
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, String_To_Bytes2(dump));

        // create a barcode reader instance 
        IBarcodeReader reader1 = new BarcodeReader();
        reader1.Options.PossibleFormats = new BarcodeFormat[] { BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE };
        // load a bitmap
        var barcodeBitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("D:\\C# Web Application\\JobTracker-Dev2\\JobTracker\\QR.jpg");
        // detect and decode the barcode inside the bitmap
        var result = reader1.Decode(barcodeBitmap);
        // do something with the result
        if (result != null)
        {
            ViewBag.Result = result.Text;
        }


    }

    private byte[] String_To_Bytes2(string strInput)
    {
        int numBytes = (strInput.Length) / 2;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[numBytes];

        for (int x = 0; x < numBytes; ++x)
        {
            bytes[x] = Convert.ToByte(strInput.Substring(x * 2, 2), 16);
        }

        return bytes;
    }


}
}
```

jquery.webcam.js

```
    (function ($) {

    var webcam = {

    "extern": null, // external select token to support jQuery dialogs
    "append": true, // append object instead of overwriting

    "width": 320,
    "height": 240,

    "mode": "callback", // callback | save | stream

    "swffile": "jscam.swf",
    "quality": 85,

    "debug":    function () {},
    "onCapture":    function () {},
    "onTick":   function () {},
    "onSave":   function () {},
    "onLoad":   function () {}
    };

    window["webcam"] = webcam;

    $["fn"]["webcam"] = function(options) {

    if (typeof options === "object") {
        for (var ndx in webcam) {
        if (options[ndx] !== undefined) {
            webcam[ndx] = options[ndx];
        }
        }
    }

    var source = '<object id="webcamobject" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="'+webcam["swffile"]+'" width="'+webcam["width"]+'" height="'+webcam["height"]+'"><param name="movie" value="'+webcam["swffile"]+'" /><param name="FlashVars" value="mode='+webcam["mode"]+'&amp;quality='+webcam["quality"]+'" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /></object>';

    if (null !== webcam["extern"]) {
        $(webcam["extern"])[webcam["append"] ? "append" : "html"](source);
    } else {
        this[webcam["append"] ? "append" : "html"](source);
    }

    var run = 3;
    (_register = function() {
        var cam = document.getElementById('webcamobject');

        if (cam && cam["capture"] !== undefined) {

        /* Simple callback methods are not allowed :-/ */
        webcam["capture"] = function(x) {
            try {
            return cam["capture"](x);
            } catch(e) {}
        }
        webcam["save"] = function(x) {
            try {
            return cam["save"](x);
            } catch(e) {}
        }
        webcam["setCamera"] = function(x) {
            try {
            return cam["setCamera"](x);
            } catch(e) {}
        }
        webcam["getCameraList"] = function() {
            try {
            return cam["getCameraList"]();
            } catch(e) {}
        }
        webcam["pauseCamera"] = function() {
            try {
            return cam["pauseCamera"]();
            } catch(e) {}
        }       
        webcam["resumeCamera"] = function() {
            try {
            return cam["resumeCamera"]();
            } catch(e) {}
        }
        webcam["onLoad"]();
        } else if (0 == run) {
        webcam["debug"]("error", "Flash movie not yet registered!");
        } else {
        /* Flash interface not ready yet */
        run--;
        window.setTimeout(_register, 1000 * (4 - run));
        }
    })();
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: By "_it wont show the information_" you mean that `ViewBag.Result` never gets set or that it does get set but the information isn't what you expected?

Comment: sorry the ViewBag.Result never gets set :)

Comment: Assuming you're using ZXing.Net for the decoding, try setting possible barcode formats before decoding, somehow like this: `reader1.Options.PossibleFormats = new BarcodeFormat[] { BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE }`

Comment: still no success, im wondering has it got anything to do with using a javascript to display the information?

Comment: Firstly, don't use in-line events for JS. Secondly, is `webcam.capture()` even a JS function?

Comment: @goldeneye Debug your program and see if the result is _actually_ null.

Comment: @Sippy i have a JS file with all the commands for the webcam...this does work as i can see the image captured in my drive.....

Comment: Show the code for `webcam.capture()` please. You also need to edit your question and make it clear enough for people to answer, as it stands you haven't given enough information and your question is too broad.

Comment: @Sippy question has been amended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ditched this method in favour of JSQRcode